# jQuery Datatables: .page('last') not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Statement:**

I am using [jquery datatables](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29). I have a button and on click I want *datatables* to go the last page.

I have been messing with [.page()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29) for 2 hours and couldn't make it work..
Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I am using the same options as given [on this page](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29)

See this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/pdoo0khs/) for example.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="">Last Page</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": url
    });
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        table.page('last').draw(false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to type in the ID

```
<button id="">Last Page</button>
```

to

```
<button id="next">Last Page</button>
```

Other than that the example works fine!

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pdoo0khs/1/)

change:

```
<button id="lastpage">Last Page</button>

$('#lastpage').on('click', function () {
        table.page('last').draw(false);
});
```